# Como exibir um Toast dentro de uma Thread no Android?

Tags: android, thread

Estou desenvolvendo um aplicativo e eu precisava exibir um Toast em algum momento dentro de uma Thread, porém não estou conseguindo, alguém sabe como é possível e se é possível fazer isso? Agradeço desde já.

Obs: se não for um toast, poderia ser um Dialog também, mas da o mesmo problema.

Comment: Tem algum código já feito? Clique em [edit] e adicione na pergunta para facilitar a analise.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

A razão é que não é permitido aceder a objectos que usam a UI, como é o caso de *Toast*, em uma *Thread* que não a *UIThread(MainThread)*.

No método `run()` da *Thread* use o método `runOnUiThread()` para colocar um *Runnable* na *UIThread*.

```
new Thread() {
    public void run() {

        ....
        ....
        runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {

            @Override
            public void run() {

                //Coloque aqui o código que necessita de correr
                //na UI thread, como por exemplo o Toast
            }
        });

    }
}.start();
```

**Nota:** O mesmo se aplica caso tenha siso uma AsyncTask e se pretenda usar o Toast no `doInBackground()`.

Comment: Funcionou perfeitamente como eu precisava. obrigadão!

Answer (score 4):

Penso que o que precisas é chamar o Toast.makeTexts da UI Thread, dentro da tua thread podes fazer assim:

```
activity.runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
  public void run() {
    Toast.makeText(activity, "Sou um toast dentro de uma thread", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
  }
});
```