# Execução de threads no android

Tags: java, android, thread

Sou novo no trabalho com `threads` no Android e estou tendo dificuldades para implementa-las.

A `thread` será utilizada para fazer um calculo e por ultimo enviar um e-mail dependendo do resultado do calculo, porém não estou conseguindo implementa-la nem para chamar um simples `toast` devido a exceção:

> java.lang.RuntimeException: Can't create handler inside thread that has not called Looper.prepare();

Não sei se é porque estou utilizando ela na Activity do usuário e não sei como resolver, poderiam me ajudar ? Segue os códigos relacionados

**MainActivity:**

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
//ATRIBUTOS
private ArrayAdapter adapter;
private ListView listView;
private ArrayList<Coins> arrayList;
private Toolbar toolbar;

private final long intervalo = 10000;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    //CONFIGURANDO A TOOLBAR
    toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
    toolbar.setTitle("CoinmarketCap");
    setSupportActionBar(toolbar); //indispensavel para o funcionamento da toolbar

    //********* CONFIGURANDO A LISTAGEM DAS MOEDAS **********/
    listView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.lv_coins);

    arrayList = new ArrayList<>();
    adapter = new CoinsAdapter(MainActivity.this, arrayList);
    listView.setAdapter(adapter);

    //********* FIM CONFIGURANDO A LISTAGEM DAS MOEDAS **********/
    recarregar();

    //EXECUTANDO A TAREFA DE CALCULO
    Timer timer = new Timer();
    TimerTask tarefa = new TimerTask() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            try{
                Inbackground inbackground = new Inbackground(MainActivity.this);
                inbackground.run();
            } catch (Exception e){
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    };
    timer.scheduleAtFixedRate(tarefa, intervalo, intervalo);
}
```

**Classe que extende TimerTask:**

```
public class Inbackground extends TimerTask {
private Context context;

public Inbackground(Context c){
    this.context = c;
}

@Override
public void run() {
    Toast.makeText(context, "Rodando a thread", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
}
}
```

Não sei se essa é a melhor maneira de conseguir realizar a tarefa do calculo e envio por e-mail, caso exista uma maneira mais fácil ou melhor em questão à desempenho ficarei feliz em conhece-la.

Comment: Se o seu problema for apenas o Toast veja [Como exibir um Toast dentro de uma Thread no Android?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/95091/2541).

Answer (score 1):

O melhor jeito de implementar isso é utilizando AsyncTask, fica mais ou menos assim:

```
  class Tarefa extends AsyncTask<String, String, String> {

        ProgressDialog dialog = new ProgressDialog(this);
        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute() {
            super.onPreExecute();
            dialog.setMessage("Acessando...");
            dialog.setCancelable(false);
            dialog.show();
        }
        @Override
        protected String doInBackground(String... strings) {
            int a = 4+5;

            return String.valueOf(a);               
        }
        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(String s) {
            super.onPostExecute(s);

           Toast.makeText(Main.this,s, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    }
```

E aí você chama onde quiser, desse jeito:  `new Tarefa().execute();`

Comment: Do jeito que você está fazendo não vai conseguir mandar mensagem durante a thread, ah não ser se implementar o Handler, desta forma:  

Handler h = new Handler(Looper.getMainLooper());
        h.post(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                Toast.makeText( SuaActivity.this.getBaseContext(), "Texto", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        });

Comment: Se possível clique em [edit] e adicione o código do comentário na sua resposta.

Answer (score 0):

```
Você pode usar esse dois passo que montei.

1 - Primeiro crie uma classe chamada AsyncControl

public class AsyncControl {

private ProgressDialog mProgressDialog;

    public static void runAsync(final AsyncListiner listiner, final Context context, final String title) {
        run(listiner, context, title, true);
    }

    public static void runAsync(final AsyncListiner listiner, final Context context, final String title, boolean showDialog) {
        run(listiner, context, title, showDialog);
    }

    public static void runAsync(final AsyncListiner listiner, final Context context,boolean showDialog) {
        run(listiner, context, "", showDialog);
    }

    public static void run(final AsyncListiner listiner, final Context context, final String title, final boolean showDialog) {
        new AsyncTask() {
            Dialog dialog;

            @Override
            protected void onPreExecute() {
               mProgressDialog = new ProgressDialog(activity);
               mProgressDialog.setIndeterminate(false);
               mProgressDialog.setProgressStyle(ProgressDialog.STYLE_SPINNER);
                if (showDialog)
                    dialog.show();
            }

            @Override
            protected Object doInBackground(Object[] objects) {
                listiner.run();
                return null;
            }

            @Override
            protected void onPostExecute(Object o) {
                dialog.dismiss();
                listiner.onComplete();
            }
        }.execute();
    }

    public interface AsyncListiner {
        void run();
        void onComplete();
    }
}

2 - Para chamar o metodo em modo async

 AsyncControl.runAsync(new AsyncControl.AsyncListiner() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                /// o que deve ser feito em background
            }

            @Override
            public void onComplete() {
              /// Quando termina de executar em background
            }
        },mContext,"Esse é um titulo");
```